# JQuery : how to hide div after animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to hide dive after the animation. Is it possible ?

I can show you code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/5WcPx/6/)**

Comment: Which `<div>` do you want to hide? `#main`? Or do you want to remove the `<div>` that was animated entirely?

Comment: @minitech i need to hide `div1` to show div2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a callback to `animate` as the second argument. Also, you'll need to change `.next()` to something else to find only the first child, and there are a few other optimizations that can be made. Your CSS is also wrong. [Here's the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5WcPx/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var $lefty = $(this).next().children().eq(0);

        $lefty.animate({
            left: -$lefty.outerWidth()
        }, function() {
            $lefty.next().show();
            $lefty.remove();
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

As a fourth param, [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) can take a callback to execute on complete. Alternatively, just use a `complete` attribute on your options object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var $lefty = $(this).next();
        $lefty.animate({
            left: (parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0),
            complete: function () {
                /* Do hide here */
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hide the div in there perhaps by calling `hide()` on `this`.

Comment: It's actually not the fourth attribute. The jQuery function accepts the parameters in that order, but they're all optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to be called on completion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    }, function () {
      $lefty.hide();
    });
  });
});​
```